# Centering a div horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I must be missing something really simple here:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="/add" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp; Add User
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" ng-show="users.busy">
        <div class="spinner-loader center-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've used the bootstrap classes, including `center-block`. Yet it always looks like this:

[image]

Why isn't the spinner icon in the centre of the page?

Comment: you want center horizontally as well as vertically?

Comment: what bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: No I don't care about vertically, I just want it centred horizontally. I'm on v3.3.4

Comment: Please include all relevant code to allow us to reproduce the issue you see in your image. My guess is that `.spinner-loader` does not have any `width` but without knowing the styles applied to `.spinner-loader` I can't be certain.

Comment: You have asked the question well and good but missed the essential part of including the CSS for `spinner-loader` A demo would be way better.

Comment: For future people looking at this question; the spinner loader CSS was from http://www.css-spinners.com/css/spinner/spinner.css - thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a work around to your problem by changing some HTML as follows

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center" ng-show="users.busy">
        <span class="spinner-loader">Loading</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

instead of `<div>` for spinner I took a `<span>` which will be centered horizontally because of `text-center` class to parent `<div>`.

Comment: You may be right, but without knowing the styles applied to `.spinner-loader` your answer is just a guess at the moment.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes: Yes, I'm riding on the guess at the moment. I saw your comment below the question. and I am too waiting for OP to post CSS code. :)

Comment: @HiddenHobbes: Its not the case always, you have to think in a positive way. There is a very thin difference between reality and guess at the moment.

Comment: Nilesh, you got it right in this instance so everything is hunky dorey, but this isn't about being positive it's about providing answers. Guesses a) may not answer the question and b) give the impression that asking incomplete questions is ok. I've got no beef with you, just want to ensure questions are useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="/add" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> &nbsp; Add User
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<center>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12" ng-show="users.busy">
        <div class="spinner-loader"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `center-block`, add `text-center` class

Answer (score 0):

I ve been using the bootstrap `col-md-offset` css to center my divs. For example:

```
<div class=container>
<div class=row>
    <div class=form-horizontal>
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="your div">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your div will be responsive, thus as you resize the window the div will remain in the center of the window.